# How do I select inputs having a name like "abc[]" with Prototypejs?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I want to select an input with Prototypejs and its $$ function.

I am able to do this :

```
$$('input')
```

But I want to be more accurate in my search, with a name of an input.
The name of the input I want to select is "array[]" :

```
$$('input[name="array[]"]')
```

I think the [ and ] in the name are creating troubles because the result I get are the same as if I did this :

```
$$('input')
```

How do i select the inputs having a name such as "something[]" ?

Comment: Only IE exhibits this behavior in prototype. `$$('input[name="array[]"]')` works in every other browser. What browser and what Prototype version are you using?

Comment: Prototype 1.5.1 with Firefox.

Also tried with 1.6.0.3.

Comment: Which Firefox? Works on my FF 3.0.13 with Prototype 1.5.2 (win).

Comment: Firefox 3.5.2.

Try to put others inputs in your document, <input type="text" name="array[]" />, <input type="text" name="test" />

My Firefox returns all inputs I just want array[].

Comment: I think we had a bug in 1.6.0.3. Does this happen in 1.6.1 (released yesterday)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like it was a bug with prototype 1.6.0.3 and probably lower versions.

Works with prototype >= 1.6.1

Answer (score 3):

You can be a little more verbose and use :

```
$$('input').findAll(function (o) { return o.name=="array[]"; })
```

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to be able not to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you probably looking for

```
$$('input[name="array[]"]')[0]
```

because `$$()` returns an array of input elements? Works for me.

Comment: Works for me too but as I described it returns every input elements in the document.

I want an array of the elements having the name array[], not the others.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with prototype selectors. Btw, `$('input[name="array[]"]')` works in jQuery.